# Network Adapter in AC Mode

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

Not a networking expert here.  Just upgraded and installed the ASUS RT-AC68U router.  Installation was smooth with no issue.  I have the T440s laptop running Windows 8.1 with the "Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260" adapter and I checked the device manager > wireless mode and still shows 6.802.11a/b/g.  How can I update the adapter to AC mode?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the device settings? They’re not a status display.